# Error in remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging in my application and while using the Firebase console my application in Android and iOS receives my notifications. But because I wanted to push notification daily I created a cron job to do that in my server side. I notice that every time i trigger my cron my application crashes

In my iOS client it doesn't receive any notification.

In my android client it displays an error:

`java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference`

Where it is in my `FirebaseMessagingService` here is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

And in my server-side

```
function sendNotificationFCM($apiKey, $registrationIDs, $messageText,$id) {


$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey
);

$message = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array(
            "message" => $messageText,
            "id" => $id,
    ),
);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($message)
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}
```

I'm wondering why am I having a NPE and how can I solve it?

Comment: Where's the notification object in your $message?

Comment: @sinense I don't have `notification` object, i thought `data` is enough, because `notification` is optional. Should I add it in my `$message`? What should I put in `notification` object?

Comment: yes notification object is by default optional. But on your onMessageReceived(), you're calling remoteMessage.getNotification() but you don't have a notification object to parse.

Comment: @sinense it works now thanks! :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to add a notification object on your $message. The body of your POST request must be something like:

```
{
    "to" : "aUniqueKey",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
}
```

Your `remoteMessage.getNotification()` returns`null` because the body of your POST request doesn't contain a notification object.

> Use notifications when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want your app to handle the display or process the messages on your Android client app, or if you want to send messages to iOS devices when there is a direct FCM connection.

Check the [Documentation for Advanced Messaging Options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for your reference.

Comment: you are awesome

Answer (score 1):

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
   sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

Comment: People have given a negative vote on this but this is an actual answer, all you want to check if getNotification() returns null, if not, you can request for the body.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sendNotificationFCM($apiKey, $registrationIDs, $messageText,$id) {



    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey
    );

    $message = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array(
                "message" => $messageText,
                "id" => $id,
        ),
     'notification' => array(
                "body" => "body of notification",
                "title" => "title for notification",
        )
    );


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($message)
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found out the solution through few experiments.

I am using Node backend where my Sample Push (Taken from Google Firebase) looks like:

```
const message = {
    data: {score: '850', time: '2:45'},
    tokens: nTokenArray
}


admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.failureCount > 0) {
      const failedTokens = [];
      response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
        if (!resp.success) {
          console.log('resperrorresperrorresperrorresperror', resp.error);
          failedTokens.push(registrationTokens[idx]);
        }
      });
      console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + failedTokens);
    }
  })
  .catch(fcmError => {
    console.log({'FCM Errors': fcmError});
  })
```

At Android Side:

```
Log.d(TAG, "BodyScore: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("score"));
```

`NullPointerException` is due to when you use `getNotification().getBody()` instead of `getData().get("score")` when you are using `Data Payload` instead of `Notification Payload` at server side:

```
const message = {
    data: {score: '850', time: '2:45'},
    tokens: nTokenArray
}
```